# Why does the following equality hold? $\sec^{-1}(2/\sqrt{2}) = \sec^{-1}(\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is $\sec^{-1}(2/\sqrt{2}) = \sec^{-1}(\sqrt{2})$ true?

Comment: This seems to be more of an arithmetic problem than a trigonometry problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since

$$
\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}.
$$

In general, for $a\geqslant0$ we have

$$
\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{a}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

As Workaholic pointed out (here with more explanation):
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\tag{$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=1$}\\[1em]
                   &= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2}\\[1em]
                   &= \sqrt{2}.
\end{align}
Since $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$, it must then be true that
$$
\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{2}),
$$
as desired.